# .NET CSC.EXE output file format

Tags: .net, clr, .net-assembly

So, I'm interested with .NET runtime architecture and structure. I want to know how it works step by step. I have several books, also looking for in google some answers but now, I want correct answer about some questions.

In books written that, CSC.exe ( compiler ) generates managed module, that contains:
1. PE Header
2. CLR Header
3. Metadata
4. IL Code

and after compilation, tool AL.exe ( assembly linker ) merges that module/s into assembly.
I also know that, assembly have two main file extension: DLL or EXE.

But, I'm interested about Managed modules. How it compiles compiler and what the file format have ? does it an .netmodule extension ? OR DLL ?

p.s
Sorry for my english.

Comment: Read ECMA335. Fun and informative.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm

Comment: No guys. I understood what is IL code and so on. My question is about Managed module extension. Sometime I read that, module and assembly have same extension ( DLL ). Sometime I read that, module have .netmodule extension. There is some vagueness What exactly file extension have an module ( Managed module ).

We know that, Managed module have 4 main point:
1. PE Header;
2. CLR Header;
3. Metadata;
4. IL Code;

But what is physically managed module. What extension have it when language compiler creates it from high level code ?

Answer (score 1):

Managed modules are just like .DLL/.EXE in format (they are both PE format, they contain PE header + CLR Header + metadata + code).
The difference is that you create a .netmodule if you are doing a multi-module assembly.  A multi-module assembly is an assembly that has multiple modules inside it,  System.Data.dll is an example of that, since it has both a managed part, and a native C++ part into 1 assembly.

.NetModules are just a convenient way to package multiple modules into 1 assembly.  High level compilers (like C#) don't deal with it, that is why you need to use the Assembly Linker tool  (AL).

Hope this helps
Thanks